# How to drag and drop a component on a pdf page in selenium?

Tags: selenium

I can drag it but cannot drop it on the pdf page. I have tried the all the possible ways of drag and drop but unable to drop the component on pdf.

I can drag-and-drop this manually, but in automation, it is not happening. I will share the manual video:  https://drive.500apps.com/HYS2CsEMGNIBwC4FcBOBTAtAR0hgrAAwBMBGAjAMwECcA7AHRxIBGANiNNpPYQfHAGd6AexQBzAPQA3EABM0wiWQAcANlV4gA

Comment: Are you able to drag-and-drop this manually? I would expect not.

Comment: I can do this manually but in automation, it is not happening. I will share the manual video
https://drive.500apps.com/HYS2CsEMGNIBwC4FcBOBTAtAR0hgrAAwBMBGAjAMwECcA7AHRxIBGANiNNpPYQfHAGd6AexQBzAPQA3EABM0wiWQAcANlV4gA